# SwiftyJSON Problems Swift 2

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I have a API URL that return JSON data, which you can find here https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=25/json

I want to return all of the movie titles in this JSON data.

I am using the SwiftyJSON Framework to parse the JSON data from the URL. I am using a NSURLSession.dataTask to begin the Parse from the URL.

The problem is that the JSON data I want to return is not returning anything.

Here is some code -

JSON Data URL -

```
let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=25/json"
```

Retrieving JSON Data

```
 func getTheJSONData() throws {



    let theURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: theURL!)


    //let JSONError : NSError?



    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in


        do {

            if error == nil{

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

                let Name = swiftyJSON["feed"]["entry"][0]["im:name"]["label"].stringValue


                //prints nil..
                print(Name)


            }


        } catch {
            // report error

            print(error)
        }

}
    task.resume()


}
```

Comment: I tried your code and [it worked](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFlfzCDnQ99H9Y9HttHhrhM9x-YEjdUEU10) (Xcode 7.0.1)

Comment: @EricD. Did it print a list of movie titles?

Comment: Look at the screenshot I linked. Of course not, because your code asks for *one title*. So it prints the title. It doesn't print `nil` as says your comment in the code.

Comment: @EricD. Is there a way to retrieve more than one movie title?

Comment: Yes of course. :) I made an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does exactly what it's supposed to: it prints the title of a movie.

With this:

```
let Name = swiftyJSON["feed"]["entry"][0]["im:name"]["label"].stringValue
print(Name)
```

you get the title of one movie because you're getting the first element of the array with `[0]`.

Since you want to get all movies titles, instead of working with the first element, work with all elements. Example:

```
let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

let movies = swiftyJSON["feed"]["entry"].arrayValue

let titles = movies.map { $0["im:name"]["label"].stringValue }

print(titles)
```

`print(titles)` gives an array of titles:

> ["Jurassic World", "Avengers: Age of Ultron", "Spy", "Entourage", "Pixels", "Froning", "Pitch Perfect 2", "Cartel Land", "Aladdin", "Furious 7 (Extended Edition)", "Magic Mike XXL", "\'71", "The Age of Adaline", "Cast Away", "Cinderella (2015)", "San Andreas", "Mad Max: Fury Road", "Hotel Transylvania", "Paddington", "Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol", "Aloha", "Dope", "Man on Wire", "Me and Earl and the Dying Girl", "The Overnight"]

By the way, as the compiler says with the warning, there's no need to use `do catch` for `JSON()` because it doesn't throw.